# Running node app in VPS gives error but error not present in work laptop

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, vps

When I run `node app` in a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 17.04 x64 VPS server, I get the following error:

```
/root/myApp/node_modules/natural/lib/natural/brill_pos_tagger/lib/Brill_POS_Tagger.js:26
logger.setLevel('WARN');
       ^

TypeError: logger.setLevel is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/myApp/node_modules/natural/lib/natural/brill_pos_tagger/lib/Brill_POS_Tagger.js:26:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/myApp/node_modules/natural/lib/natural/index.js:81:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

However, when I run node app with the same stuff on my work laptop, it runs normally.

I thought at first it might be an error with google cloud API installation, however, after installing it on my VPS, I still got the same error.

Is there anything else that might be the cause of this error? I am running `node app` on the same exact code on my laptop and it runs fine.